# Get Row's Index In Data Source

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-grid, how can I retrieve the row's index from the data array, not the `.rowIndex` property as the `rowIndex` property can change when sorting and filtering is applied.  The data structure doesn't have an identifier, so I can't look for an Id while iterating the data.  (See Mike Smith example below).  Per the example below, when a sort is applied, how can I get the " original index" property?

I need to be able to do something along the lines of `node.index` instead of `node.rowIndex`.

```
// Data I provide ag-grid
const unsortedData = [
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}, // original index 0, rowIndex 0
  {firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jones'}, // original index 1, rowIndex 1
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}, // original index 2, rowIndex 2
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Johnson'} // original index 3, rowIndex 3
];
```

```
// Example of internally sorted data by ag-grid.  IE `rowsAfterSort`. 
const sortedData = [
  {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Johnson'}, // original index 3, rowIndex 0
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}, // original index 0, rowIndex 1
  {firstName: 'Mike', lastName: 'Smith'}, // original index 2, rowIndex 2
  {firstName: 'Steve', lastName: 'Jones'} // original index 1, rowIndex 3
];
```

```
// Callback function from ag-grid
function myAgGridCallback(params){
  // var realIndex = params.node.rowIndex;  //rowIndex changes when sorting is applied
  // var realIndex = params.node.index; // I need something like this.  index does not exist.

  // Do stuff with realIndex
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's just an array of objects so maybe try ```sortedData[0].firstName```?

Comment: @EvanGertis, I added an example to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Would params be the sortedData?

Comment: Nope.  params is a complex object provided by ag-grid.  The params object contains the APIs provided by ag-grid, but I don't see a way to access the unsorted index.

Comment: Can you add an  property called ```index```, set the real index to it, ignore it in the sort, and then access it off the params that are returned?

Answer (score 1):

A good approach to solve this would be inserting a unique identifier on each element, which would result in a strong bond among your data set.

Since you said that it's not possible to do, you can use ag-grid generated ID which will also serve as an index to your data.

> As [ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/) says:
>
> > The easiest way to get a rowNode is by its ID. The ID is either
> >     provided by you using the grid callback getRowNodeId(), or generated
> >     by the grid using an internal sequence.

So in your case, one of the solutions would be using `getDisplayedRowAtIndex` method. On your second example, after data is sorted, you could do:

```
this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0).id
// where 0 is your rowIndex
```

and this would result in the value `3` as you expected. Basically, for each node you access it will have an `id` property and it will serve as an index on the original array.
Depending on your application you could also use `forEachNode` method that as documentation describes:

> Iterates through each node (row) in the grid and calls the callback
>   for each node. This works similar to the 'forEach' method on a
>   Javascript array. This is called for every node, ignoring any
>   filtering or sorting applied within the grid. If using infinite row
>   model, then gets called for each page loaded in the page cache.